# How to release memory from one that used by tf.data.generator in tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I am using tf.data.generator to feed large dataset for training something like that...

```
function getRemote() {
 return tf.tidy(() => {
      ....
      ...
      return [X,y];
 }
}
async function mydata() {
    ....
    ....
    // getting my large dataset...
   ..
   const iterator = {
       ....
       ...
       var remote = getRemote();
       return {value: { xs: remote[0], ys: remote[1] }, done:..}
    }
   return iterator;
}

var ds = tf.data.generator(mydata);
var history = await mymodel.fitDataset(ds, {
    epochs:5,
     ...
    ...
  }
});
```

Well...the thing is that I need to dispose those tensors(which are xs,ys) that generated from the generator once the train was done I believe, in order to avoid memory leaking..

What would be best way to dispose those tensors that have been fed by tf.data.generator?

I was thinking that ..maybe.... onBatchEnd I could use from the fitDataset as a callback..in there..somehow..I could dispose them..however, the things is that I couldn't figure out how to access those tensor data in onBatchEnd callback...Would that be even possible?

In every batch, those tensor data keeps generating and feeding from the generator....so I believe I definitely need to dispose properly somehow..

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [tf.tidy](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tidy) to dispose tensors that are not used. It is handy because it can surround a bloc of operations and all intermediate tensors are disposed.

To dispose a single tensor, you can call the method dispose of the tensor `tensor.dispose()`

Comment: I don't think I can use tf.tidy in this context I was asking. I am using generator..I am not asking to dispose intermediate ones... ones that actually generated and used in fitdataset...I need to dispose them once they are done by fit....I still think the best place would be in OnBatchEnd though..If that is true, then how would I be able to access those ones in OnBatchEnd? That is my ultimate question.

Comment: Have you tried to run your code and you had a memory issue ? If so, could you please add your whole code to the question ? `fitDataset` and other operators disposes intermediate tensors once they are not needed. You can have a look at the source code on github.

Comment: So you mean....above code (xs,ys) will be disposed eventually when they are not needed? .. what if I want to dispose them explicitly? how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: As I already mentioned, you need to play around with `tf.tidy` and `dispose`. Unless you have a working code that demonstrate the issue you want to solve, I can't help you further

Comment: I am not sure what code you need to see more...above code is clear to see what I am trying to do to..xs: remote[0], ys: remote[1] ..these tensors will be going in to fitDataset to train..so..all I am trying to do...whenever batch is done, I want to dispose them explicitly those...That's why I keep saying onBatchEnd may be good candidate for that in my opinion..but I am not sure how I could access those tensor in that onBatchEnd to use dispose.....Only thing I could think of is that I may use a sort of global variable to keep track of those tensors so that I could dispose..may not work though..